# Generating a number on class instantiation

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using OOP to create a basic class and I can't figure how to randomly generate a number for the type of Weapon when each Weapon is instantiated in the main Class.

```
//Weapon.h
class Weapon {

    int type;

public:
    Weapon();
    ~Weapon();


    int getType();
};
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//Weapon.cpp
#include "Weapon.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

Weapon::Weapon()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    type = rand() % 4;
}

Weapon::~Weapon() 
{
}

int Weapon::getType() {
    return type;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Weapon.h"

int main() {

    Weapon w1, w2, w3;

    std::cout << "w1 is type #" << w1.getType() << "\n";
    std::cout << "w2 is type #" << w2.getType() << "\n";
    std::cout << "w3 is type #" << w3.getType() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The results I am getting are:
"w1 is type #1"
"w2 is type #1"
"w3 is type #0"

Everytime I run the program in Visual Studio, the same numbers appear and they aren't being randomized everytime the program runs. How would I achieve this? I seem to have forgotten the basics of c++ because this seems easy to me but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT: Using srand in Weapon.cpp, I now get random generation on each run. But all the weapons have the same type value. How would each instantiated weapon have a different type value?**

Comment: Seed your [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) with the time. `srand(time(NULL))`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq After looking through that, I now have a random number on each run but all 3 weapons are the same value. How would that be fixed?

Comment: Seed only once: `srand(time(NULL));` is `main` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //test.h
#pragma once
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
std::default_random_engine e(time(0)); //global
class Weapon {


    int type;


public:
    Weapon();
    ~Weapon();


    int getType();
};
Weapon::Weapon()
{

    type = e() % 4;
}

Weapon::~Weapon()
{
}

int Weapon::getType() {
    return type;
}
//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    //srand(time(NULL));
    Weapon w1, w2, w3;

    std::cout << "w1 is type #" << w1.getType() << "\n";
    std::cout << "w2 is type #" << w2.getType() << "\n";
    std::cout << "w3 is type #" << w3.getType() << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

let your your engine be global, or in your code, move the srand() into main.

Comment: This works but I don't understand how.

Comment: @originalwill It's quite difficult,maybe you can search "linear congruential generator" for more information,but remember that you'd better call srand() in the beginning of a process ^_^

Answer (score 1):

so the sad thing is `rand()` is a crappy random number generator... you would need to seed it at the start of the program with `srand(something)` often `srand(time(NULL))` but I am also worried about:

```
//Weapon.cpp
#include "Weapon.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int type;
```

you have a global that has the same name as a member variable... generally unwise... you can probably access them with `::type` and `this->type` but why?

Comment: srand now works and generates a new type value each time I run the program but it is the same value for each instantiated weapon. How would I make it different for each one?

Comment: @oringinalwill you are mod 2 ing it, so the values are only 1 and 0.. if you `%4` you could have 0-3... if you `%6` you could have 0-5 etc

Comment: yes I know but if I make it `%4` and have it print out each weapons value, they are all the same value. I updated the **Weapon.cpp**

Comment: @originalwill are you sranding every time? You just do it once.